# Formatting output from mailto:

Tags: html

I'm making a form which collect some data from a person and then use a simple `mailto:` to put it in their e-mail client like so (example):

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:email@address.com?subject=Stuff">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p>Address: <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p>City: <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p>Comment: <input type="text" name="Comment" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="SEND"></p>
</form>
```

It then comes out like this:

```
Name=Bob&Address=something&City=more&Comment=elsemore
```

but what I want is:

```
Name=Bob
Address=something
City=more
Comment=elsemore
```

or even better:

```
Name = Bob
Address = something
City = more
Comment = elsemore
```

Is it at all possible currently to do this just within HTML? HTML5 and Python is all I know (mostly only the basic parts too). Maybe someone could help me out with the proper code/script on this.

I did find some other posts on this but they are old and don't answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Encryption Type (`enctype="text/plain"`):

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:email@address.com?subject=Stuff" enctype="text/plain">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p>Address: <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p>City: <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p>Comment: <input type="text" name="Comment" placeholder="Number"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="SEND"></p>
</form>
```

You could also write some stuff in `Javascript` and then work with the `body` parameter. But i wouldn't recommend this.

In most times, it is better to let the webserver handle the email communication.

Asp: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371417/Send-Mail-Contact-Form-using-ASP-NET-and-Csharp

Php: http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/